# SQL Logic In Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to implement some logic in an sql query to create a table similar to:

```
Count   Name
1         a
1         a
1         a
2         b
2         b
3         c
4         d
4         d
5         e
5         e
5         e
5         e
```

As you can see, the logic is a new count starts with each name change, but this count remains as if if the name is not changed.

Comment: Google `DENSE_RANK()` windowing function.

Comment: You should include more information in your question. There is no SQL posted.  What did the original data look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
SELECT Name,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Name) [Count]
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: This will give you all ones, you dont need `PARTITION BY` here.